# Codeigniter not creating any log files

Tags: codeigniter, logging

Under `config.php` I have:

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 4;
$config['log_path'] = '/home/myaccount/logFilesFolder';
```

In index.php I have:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

The only way I can seem to get anything to log is if I chmod that directory to rwx (777), which doesn't seem right to me. That and it doesn't see to be logging all the errors.

In my local/dev environment it seems to be working but on my production server nothing is being logged. I can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: did your problem solved?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

***The log filename in the configuration settings needs a trailing "/"*** above making sure the webserver process has writeable access to the directory.

Answer (score 5):

Change the logs owner and group to what owner/group your live web server is running, give it write perms and it should work. I take it that in your local/dev server your CI folder is owned by you that is why you need to chmod it to 777 to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

The directory where you want the log files to be saved needs to be writable.

Comment: thank you!!!! dont know how many times ive restarted the server to get this wokring

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a lot of solutions and finally what worked for me was this:

Open system/libraries/Log.php
and change the following lines;
set the value of: $this->log_path to a writable directory, preferably home directory so that there are no permission issues. If you want to change the filename also, search for the variable $filepath and change the name.
Example:
    $this->log_path = '/log';
    touch /log/
restart the webserver. 
The logs will start coming.

I have tried a lot of other options, none worked, this is not neat approach but at least I can see my logs now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Codeigniter 4 project. The log was created successfully in my local window machine but was not creating on the remote Linux machine. I was using a custom path to generate log files under the 'app' folder. So what I did is to change the settings in my config/Logger.php file back to

```
'path' => WRITEPATH.'logs/',
```

and it created the log files under writeable/logs folder.