# log file in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to create a error log file in codeigniter. As per the rules i changed the  value $config['log_threshold'] = 1; in config.php file. Error log file was created in the logs folder. But i wrongly deleted that file. I wrote the coding like this

```
 $data['name'] = "Somename";
 $add_department = $this->db->insert('mas_factory',$data);
 if($add_department == false)
 { 
     log_message('error', 'Table field name is wrong.');    
 }
```

error log file is not automatically generated. But i need to see the error messages in error log file. How to create a log file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6560739/3164682

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do error logging in CodeIgniter (PHP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209807/how-to-do-error-logging-in-codeigniter-php)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make your `/application/log`s folder writable

In `/application/config/config.php` set

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 1;
```

Use `log_message('error', 'Some variable did not contain a value.');`

If you deleted the file simply re upload..`

Comment: @sathish It doesn't make a difference

Comment: Instead of using try catch Exception, i use error log ?

Comment: yeah you can change it